# Changes in edit mode not showing up in object mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, object-mode

long time lurker here.

I've been trying to create a character mesh, and it looks fine in edit mode.  I can edit, make changes, and save with no problems.  However, in Object mode it appears as a rectangular prism.

[image: Edit mode image]

[image: Object mode image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the properties *Window > Object > Display > Maximum Draw Type* dropdown menu make sure it isn't in *Bounds* mode

[image: Box]

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much for answering my question